# X509 structure to human readable string

Tags: c, openssl

How would I go about converting a X509 certificate in C into human readable string. For example:

```
X509* cert;
```

into

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conversion of X509 structure to the string with PEM encoded certificate:

```
char *X509_to_PEM(X509 *cert) {

    BIO *bio = NULL;
    char *pem = NULL;

    if (NULL == cert) {
        return NULL;
    }

    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    if (NULL == bio) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (0 == PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, cert)) {
        BIO_free(bio);
        return NULL;
    }

    pem = (char *) malloc(bio->num_write + 1);
    if (NULL == pem) {
        BIO_free(bio);
        return NULL;    
    }

    memset(pem, 0, bio->num_write + 1);
    BIO_read(bio, pem, bio->num_write);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return pem;
}
```

Conversion of PEM encoded certificate to the X509 structure:

```
X509 *PEM_to_X509(char *pem) {

    X509 *cert = NULL;
    BIO *bio = NULL;

    if (NULL == pem) {
        return NULL;
    }

    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(pem, strlen(pem));
    if (NULL == bio) {
        return NULL;
    }

    cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return cert;
}
```

Comment: Is there any lost information in the translation? In other words, could I do X509 -> .pem -> X509, and have the same structure?

Comment: @kmdent Nothing is lost. You can read PEM encoded cert to X509 structure with PEM_read_bio_X509() function.