# how to load .cer to x509 with openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, rsa, x509certificate, x509

I have a .cer file starts with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and end with "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", now I need to load it to check signature with openssl, those are what i've tried:

```
FILE *pub_fp = fopen(certpath.c_str(), "r");

1. RSA *rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(pub_fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
2. RSA *rsa = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(pub_fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

// rsa is NULL

```
3. X509 *x509 = PEM_read_X509(pub_fp, NULL, 0, NULL);
4. x509 = d2i_X509_fp(pub_fp, NULL);
5. unsigned char *str;
   fread(str, 1, cert_len, fp);
   x509 = der_to_x509(ca_der, ca_der_len);
```

// x509 is NULL

And I've tested that .cer file in Java using CertificateFactory, Certificate, Signature, it checks OK.

what can I do now? did i miss something?

Comment: Try to combine 5th approach with [PEM_to_X509](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23137774/3325704) function.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?

`X509 *x509 = PEM_read_X509(pub_fp, NULL, 0, NULL);`

works for me and reads in the X509 certificate. You can retrieve certificate components including the public key from this.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code when i try to load a cer file it's in Qt but you can simply write the equivalent in any language. basically I'm read the cer file in a bio and then convert bio to x509.

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();    

BIO* bio_cert = NULL;
X509 *maincert = NULL;

QByteArray ba = FILE_ADDRESS.toLatin1();
const char *c_str2 = ba.data();
bio_cert = BIO_new_file(c_str2, "rb");

if(bio_cert != NULL)
     maincert = d2i_X509_bio(bio_cert, NULL);
```