# how to convert public key to string using openSSL api?

Tags: c, openssl

I am able to retrieve the public key contents from a cert file using openssl by following the link http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certpubkey.htm

However, it prints the public key to stdout. I want to be able to store it in a string . Is there a way to get it into a char buffer or a string ?

The line `PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(outbio, pkey)` prints to stdout.

Searched quite a bit, wasnt able to get what I wanted.

Any help will be appreciated, better if the code sample is provided as I'm running out of time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you link to sets up outbio to be stdout. I'd guess you just need to make a different output BIO instead? e.g. [BIO_s_mem](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html)

Comment: Thanks, if you could provide some code to do that, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution finally !
[X509 structure to human readable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137368/x509-structure-to-human-readable-string)

Just replaced with `EVP_PKEY *key` in `X509_to_PEM()` signature and used `PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio, key)` instead of `PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, cert)`.

Worked !